# how to use SQL created_date in python

Tags: python

Here is the python code that I have written to obtain the rows created after a particular date.

```
import csv
import os
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('{0}/{1}@{2}'.format( 'abcd', 'efgh','ijkl' ) )
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from dbname.table_name where created_date > to_date('06-APR-16','DD-MON-YY')")
row = cur.fetchall()
fp = open('eggs.csv', 'w')
myFile = csv.writer(fp)
myFile.writerows(row)
fp.close()
cur.close()
```

Am I supposed to import anything other than what I have mentioned here?

But I am getting an error as `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "CREATED_DATE": invalid identifier`

So can anyone tell me what is the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake seems to be in your SQL query.

There doesn't seem to be a "created_date" column in the table you are querying based on this error: `"CREATED_DATE": invalid identifier`

---

However, you also should write your Python slightly differently, in accordance with the [`PEP 0008 -- Style Guide for Python Code`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and common Python conventions.

For instance:

```
import csv
import cx_Oracle

# connect (cleaned your formatting a bit, I assume you use real data)
con = cx_Oracle.connect('{0}/{1}@{2}'.format('abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl'))

# execute (using the `with` context switch)
with con.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("select * from dbname.table_name where created_date > to_date('06-APR-16','DD-MON-YY')")
    row = cur.fetchall()

# write (using the `with` context switch) also csv module should be used with `rb` and `wb` modes.
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as fp:
    csv.writer(fp).writerows(row)
```

Comment: How to implement it when there is no row as such? Is there any variable which keeps track of when rows were added in Oracle?

Comment: 1. It would appear this answers your question, and you could accept my answer if you so desire. 2. If you have further questions feel free to ask another one. 3. It seems your problem is with SQL and not with Python. You should consult Oracle guides.

Comment: I saw somewhere that we could use created_date or last_modified for the same purpose. I know that it is not a column in my table.

Comment: Again, this is not a Python problem it is an SQL problem (specifically Oracle). The problem defined in the question you asked above has been explained. This answers your question, and if you know that column doesn't exist, why are you using it? [Please accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/192545)